# Can Lazy modify elements in Array in Scala?

Tags: scala

I want to define an array, each element of array is a data set read from certain path in the file system, because the data reading is costly and the position in array to be visited is sparse, so I want to use Lazy modifier to realize that one data set will not be read until being visited. How can define this kind of array?

Comment: I got a solution: I can take an case class with lazy member as elements of the array.

Answer (score 1):

Yes,we can define it with view function.

Instead of `(0 to 10).toArray`

```
scala> val a=(0 to 10).toArray
a: Array[Int] = Array(0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10)
```

`View` can not instantiate the array  but when ever we call then only it executes

```
val a=(0 to 10).view
a: scala.collection.SeqView[Int,scala.collection.immutable.IndexedSeq[Int]] = SeqView(...)

scala> for (x <- a ){
     | println(x)}
0
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
```

I hope this answered your question

Answer (score 0):

No, you cannot use `lazy` on the array to make the elements lazy. The most natural thing to do would be to use a caching library like [ScalaCache](https://github.com/cb372/scalacache).

You can also make a kind of wrapper class with a lazy field as you suggested in your comment. However, I would prefer not to expose the caching to the clients of the array. You should be able to just write `myArray(index)` to access an element.

If you don't want to use a library, this is another option (without `lazy`) that gives you an array like object with caching:

```
class CachingArray[A](size: Int, getElement: Int => A) {

  val elements = scala.collection.mutable.Map[Int, A]()

  def apply(index: Int) = elements.getOrElseUpdate(index, getElement(index))

}
```

Just initialize it with the size and a function that computes an element at a given index.

If you like, you can make it extend `IndexedSeq[A]` so it can be used more like a real array. Just implement `length` like this:

```
override def length: Int = size
```